# Algebra Iranian Olympiad Problem

Tags: inequality, contest-math

If:
$x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+xz+zy)$
 and $x,y,z \in R^+$

Prove:

$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \ge \sqrt[3]{2xyz}$

I tried my best to solve this thing but no use.
Hope you guys can help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: **Hint:** How much is $(x+y+z)^2$ ?

Comment: @lucian can you elaborate on how to use that hint? Standard inequality techniques will not work since the equality case is not when all variables are equal.

Comment: So the hint is not an actual hint in the sense of leading towards a solution, but is just something nice that you noticed?

Comment: Calvin Lin use am gm inequalyty

Comment: Thanks for your help Lucian but i've already calculated that value and tis not helping!

Comment: So far I obtained 
$$\left( \frac{x+y+z}{3} \right )^2 = \frac 4 9 \left(  xy + yz + zx \right ) \ge \frac 4 3 \left( xyz \right )^{\frac 2 3 }$$ still not good enough

Comment: And by the way I've used AM-GM inequality but that wont give me anything since in the question we got $2xyz$ in the right side of the inequality.

Comment: @mathcanbefun As I stated, as the equality condition is not when all variables are equal, you cannot take a blind approach to applying the classical inequalities, as Santosh demonstrates.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician did you check if the inequality it true via wolfram?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to show if $x,\ y,\ z\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that\begin{equation} x^2+y^2+z^2=2(xy+xz+yz)\end{equation} then\begin{equation} \frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq(2xyz)^{\frac{1}{3}}?\end{equation}

Comment: An equality condition is (1,1,4) with cyclic permutations and constant multiples.

Comment: what is $(1,1,4)$ and what is a cyclic permuation?? Calvin Lin you are confusing me

Comment: @SantoshLinkha nah!How's that done?@Nirav yup!that's it

Comment: Looks like a Lagrange multiplier optimization might work.

Comment: @MathcanbeFun I think by (1,1,4) Calvin means that if we set x=1,y=1 and z=4 we get the equality.but i aint got no idea about a cyclic permuation unless if that's $(n-1)!$ which is a permutation in which you can -for example- sit "n" number of people around a table having known that the conditions which can be turned into each other by turning the table itself are the same.

Comment: @JEM I agree, but given that this is an olympiad problem, they intend to not use calculus techniques.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Cyclic permutations mean (1, 4, 1) and (4, 1, 1). Since the variables are symmetric, any permutation will also result in an equality case.

Comment: @JEM Thanks for advice.But can you explain a bit more about how can Lagrange's MO be useful here?

Comment: @CalvinLin Ahh!Now I understand.

Comment: And of course, constant multiples mean (k, k, 4k) will work, since the expressions are all homogenous.

Comment: @FuriousMathematician Lagrange Multipliers - Stewart: Early Transcendentals chapter 11.8 problem #43. Very similar to this one

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If we put $a=\sqrt{x}$ and $b=\sqrt{y}$, the degree two equation (in $z$)
$x^2+y^2+z^2-2(xy+xz+yz)=0$ has two solutions, $(a-b)^2$ and $(a+b)^2$. By
cyclically permuting $x,y,z$, we may assume $z=(a+b)^2$. The inequality
to be shown is then equivalent to $(x+y+z)^3 \geq 54xyz$, or
$(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)^3 \geq 54(a^2b^2(a+b)^2)$. We are then done because

$$
(a^2+b^2+(a+b)^2)^3 -54(a^2b^2(a+b)^2)=2\Bigg((b-a)(2a+b)(a+2b)\Bigg)^2
$$

As guessed by CalvinLin, equality is reached exactly when
$(x,y,z)=(1,1,4)$ up to permutation.

Comment: By the way, the main identitiy is homogeneous so it is not too tedious to check it by hand.

Answer (score 10):

As the equations are all homogenous, we'd add the condition that $x+y+z=1$. This gives us $ 1 = (x+y+z)^2 = 4 (xy + yz + zx) $. Let $C = xyz$, which is a positive number. We want to show that $ 0\leq C \leq \frac{1}{54}$.

Consider the cubic equation with roots $x, y, z$. It has the form $ X^3 - X^2 + \frac{1}{4} X - C$. For a cubic equation to have 3 real roots, it must have a [non-negative discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_polynomial#The_nature_of_the_roots), which gives us $ C-54C^2 \geq 0$ ([courtesy of Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=discriminant+of+x%5E3-x%5E2%2B1%2F4x-c), sorry I screwed this up earlier), or hence that $ 0\leq C \leq \frac{1}{54}$. Hence we are done.

Comment: @Macavity I've been using this technique to [set problems](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/a-plane-a-sphere-and-a-hyperbola-walked-into-a-bar/?group=Hacn7pJbeQpC#!/solution-comments/39659/41462), which is why it came to me. It seems to work well with cases where $a = b \neq c $, and the newton sums are easily determined.

Comment: Ah, that's an approach for the toolbox then. Thanks.

Comment: @CalvinLin Adding the condition $x+y+z=1$, does it not change the given question?

Comment: How do you know that the cubic equation with roots $x,y,z$ is necessarily of the form $X^3-X^2+\frac{1}{4}X-C=0$?

Comment: @MridulSachdeva Note how he added that every single expression given is homogenous. This means that if $(x;y;z)$ is a solution, then $(tx;ty;tz)$, where $t>0$, is a solution as well. So if we have $x'+y'+z'=m$, we can multiply both sides of the equation by $t$ such that satisfies $mt=1$. Then we have $t(x'+y'+z')=mt=1$ and we can have these variables $tx', ty', tz'$ as $x,y,z$. If we can prove that the inequality and the equality holds for $x,y,z$, then that also yields that they hold for any $lx,ly,lz$, where $l>0$, as that is how homogeneity is defined.

Comment: @MridulSachdeva By multiplying out $x,y,z$ by any $l>0$ (and having the new variables called, e.g., $a,b,c$), we have $a+b+c=l$. l ranges over the whole $R^+$ set and so we can create all the other solutions for all the other sums given that we have one solution for one of the sums. I hope I've explained it well.

Comment: @mathh apply vieta formula. We have x+y+z=1 and xy+Yz+zx=1/4 and xyz=1. Hence the cubic polynomial follows.

Comment: @CalvinLin Oh, right. Should've thought about that.

Comment: @CalvinLin Is my explanation of homogeneity correct? I'm trying to get a deep understanding of it. My reasoning makes me think that if $x,y,z$ could be negative as well, then we would have to prove that the variables satisfy both the inequality and the equality when the sum is negative and when the sum is positive as two separate cases as we have to generate all the possible sums the variables can have by using the positive $t$ as a scaling agent (if $x+y+z=1$, then we can multiply $1$ by $t$ to generate all the possible positive sums and when $x+y+z=-1$, we can generate all the negative ones)

Comment: @CalvinLin And, according to my reasoning, we would have to check the third case when $x+y+z=0$ as we can't generate $0$ by scaling negative and positive numbers. So to sum all this up, given that the variables are real and everything is homogenous, would I have to prove that everything holds in three cases: when the sum of the variables is, e.g., $1$, $0$ and $-1$?

Comment: @mathh Yes, your explanation is correct. The question states that x, y, z are positive reals, (and so their sum is a positive real) and so the only case to consider is $x+y+z = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

You have:
\begin{align}
(x + y + z)^2 
  &=   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2 (x y + x z + y z) \\
  &=   4 (x y + x z + y z) \\
  &=   4 \cdot 3 \cdot \frac{x y + x z + y z}{3} \\
  &\ge 12 \sqrt[3]{x^2 y^2 z^2} \\
x + y + z
  &\ge 2 \sqrt[3]{3 x y z} \\
\frac{x + y + z}{3}
  &\ge \sqrt[3]{\frac{8}{9} x y z}
\end{align}

Comment: But $$\sqrt[3]{3}/3=\sqrt[3]{1/9}$$...

Comment: -1 please check your constants and cube / square roots. You made 2 errors. See Santosh comment up above for the correct value

Answer (score 0):

It's my old problem. See here: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h193555

My solution.

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.

Hence, the condition does not depend on $w^3$,

which says that it's enough to prove our inequality for a maximal value of $w^3$,

which happens for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=x$.

Hence, the condition gives $z(z-4x)=0$.

For $z=0$ our inequality is obviously true and for $z=4x$ we get identity.

Done!